# Pandas - converting out of order string date time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame column that has string values for date/time (Input data). I need to convert it into a semi-timestamp format (Desired output data). There are rows that are blank and need to remain blank. I use quotes for illustrative purposes. I am using `strptime` but getting an error (see below).

Input data (String):

```
Mar 8 12:00 PM  2020
'                   '
Mar 8  1:00 PM  2020
Mar 8  6:00 PM  2020
Mar 9  8:00 AM  2020
```

Desired output data:

```
3/8/2020 12:00:00
'                '
3/8/2020 13:00:00
3/8/2020 18:00:00
3/9/2020 08:00:00
```

Code:

```
import datetime as dt
df['date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%b %d %H:%M %p  %Y'))
```

Error:

```
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%b %d %H:%M %p %Y'
```

How can I rewrite this code to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with format similar like yoour with `%I` for select hours in 12H format, also is added `errors='coerce'` for missing values (`NaT`) if some value not matching:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b %d %I:%M %p  %Y', errors='coerce')
print (df)
                 date
0 2020-03-08 12:00:00
1                 NaT
2 2020-03-08 13:00:00
3 2020-03-08 18:00:00
4 2020-03-09 08:00:00
```

Last for custom format use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df['date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b %d %I:%M %p  %Y', errors='coerce')
                .dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
                .replace('NaT', ''))

print (df)
                date
0  03/08/20 12:00:00
1                   
2  03/08/20 13:00:00
3  03/08/20 18:00:00
4  03/09/20 08:00:00
```

Or replace multiple spoaces to one space:

```
df['date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['date'].replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True), format='%b %d %I:%M %p %Y', errors='coerce')
                .dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
                .replace('NaT', ''))

print (df)
                date
0  03/08/20 12:00:00
1                   
2  03/08/20 13:00:00
3  03/08/20 18:00:00
4  03/09/20 08:00:00
```

Comment: The issue is there are rows with blanks. So it needs to skip over them and apply it only to rows that are not blank. I will edit the question to show blanks in input data.

Comment: @user3062459 - If add `errors='coerce'` then it working for alldata, for blank are created missing values

Comment: this is output when I used `errors='coerce'`      0     NaT
1     NaT
2     NaT
3     NaT
4     NaT
93    NaT

Comment: @user3062459 - Are spaces in data correctly used? `%b %d %I:%M %p  %Y` - there are `2 spaces` between `%p` and `%Y`

Comment: using `replace 'Nat' ` I get all the rows blank:  0      
1      
2      
3      
4      
     ..
93     
94

Comment: It's a large dataset. Is there a way I can make all the spaces uniformed so that you code works?

Comment: Still getting blank rows when I use `replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True`. Can we discuss/talk off line?

Comment: @user3062459 I am offline now, on phone only, but if still problem is possible send me column date in csv via email? If yes, my email is in my profile, only run code for email.

Comment: What is your email? I don't see it in your profile.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to do this first for your code to work: `df['date'] = df['date'].astype(str)
df['date'] = df['date'].str.strip()`